# How do Entity Component Systems work?

Tags: c++, entity-component-system

In the project I am working on, I recently ran into a problem of software architecture:

I created a base entity class that displays a world object. Then I added functionality for the entity to have a visible piece of text attached to it.

That text is part and its supporting variables are part of the entity class. And the render class asks for these variables during the rendering part of the gameloop to render the text.

Got all of that to work. Then I started writing a derived class of the entity class to have an entity that only needs the text stuff.

That is where I started wondering whether it is better to have a text class to be entirely separate from the entity class, because there are situations where I have text that is always there with entities and sometimes I only need text without entities, however the code is almost the same.

Then I read about entity component systems. And I don't get how they work on a high level. How does the "attaching" of components work in the code?

Answer (score 0):

What you've described, where each piece of behaviour is coded directly into the entity class or a derived subclass of entity, is *not* an Entity Component System. That's just a regular inheritance hierarchy.

Those are fine for some games, especially when the number of different "kinds" of entity you need to support is small and well-defined.

But this type of inheritance hierarchy can easily get into a combinatoric explosion as the number of variations of things in your game increases, and it can be brittle to modify. A level designer who wants a new combination of behaviours for a one-off puzzle/encounter needs to wait on a programmer to make a subclass with that behaviour, or needs to use a class with a superset of all the behaviour they want plus some stuff they don't (maybe they just need a time countdown but no text, but everything deriving from entity has memory/processing cycles devoted to updating this blank text anyway). And when you want an object that combines behaviours from two disparate branches of the inheritance tree, you either need to duplicate code, move it to a point closer to the root (where it will be inherited by a lot of objects that don't need it), or use complicated "multiple inheritance" strategies that make code harder to reason about.

Component-based solutions aim to avoid these problems using [the principle of "composition over inheritance"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). Instead of baking behaviours into the specific subclass a given entity "is", we build behaviours into modular components that an entity can "have".

A simple example of this concept is to define a base `Component` class with a virtual method like `Update(Entity me, float deltaTime)`, then implement subclasses for each modular behaviour you might want to give an entity, like a `TextRenderer` component that stores and renders text.

The `Entity` class then becomes a barebones container, holding a vector of `Component` instances "attached to" that entity. When updating the entity, you iterate that collection of components and call `Update(this, deltaTime)` on each.

The `Entity` class can expose a public interface including `AddComponent` / `RemoveComponent` / `GetComponentOfType` methods to attach, detach, or address components it has. You can build new permutations of behaviour on the fly by plugging-together different modular component types, without defining a new subclass that implements all those behaviours in one type.

A good example of this strategy can be found in the Unity engine, where `GameObject` is a general-purpose "entity" that holds a list of `Component` instances. You could try downloading Unity and working through a few tutorials to get a sense of what it's like working with this kind of system, what kinds of behaviour it makes sense to separate into component types, and how the code structure looks. That way you can see how you like this before you commit to the effort of building your own implementation from scratch.

This would normally not be called an "entity component system" because the component types include both data and code to process that data themselves. In an ECS, components are often "plain old data structures", and the behaviour is separated into "systems" that iterate over all entities with a set of components matching some specific signature.

In some such implementations, "entity" ceases to exist as its own data type or object at all. Instead, you end up with big buffers of component data, linked by index, where the transform component at index 5 of the transform buffer, the renderer component at index 5 of the renderer buffer, etc. are all understood to be "owned by" "entity number 5". The entity becomes implicit in the data layout, rather than needing its own separate memory.

This is a data-oriented ECS using structure-of-arrays storage, and it lets system code like a "text rendering system" process batches of matching components very efficiently. It's useful when you want to process thousands of game entities as efficiently as possible, by making the data layout and execution order very cache-friendly and convenient to parallelize across worker threads.

Unity's new DOTS (Data Oriented Technology Stack) works this way, if you want to use that as a testing ground to see how you like this style.

As you can probably tell from the description above, it's more abstract and tricky to reason about this data-oriented version for someone new to the concept, and takes some more complex engineering to support. So if you don't need to squeeze absolute maximum throughput from your chips, you can probably afford to use the conceptually simpler version for starters, to get used to coding in terms of modular components. Then you can profile it and evaluate whether you really need the performance edge that a data-oriented refactor can bring.

Comment: I'm most fluent in C# myself, but you can check some of my past answers for examples of how to implement component-based solutions conceptually in C# style, which shouldn't be too hard to translate to the corresponding C++. You can also check out ECS libraries like [EnTT](https://github.com/skypjack/entt) (C++), Artemis (C#/Java), etc. which will include more complete and optimized examples than StackExchange answers do.